# How to access the index of a specific json key

Tags: json, flutter, dart, google-places-api

I need to access the specific key to capture the node information where the key is **administrative_area_level_2** or **administrative_area_level_1**.

[image]

I am currently accessing by index "1" or "2".

But if the json result from Google Api Places has more data, those indices will not be correct.

Is there any way to access the specific key I want to capture the city or state name?

Sample Code:

```
class Api {

  pesquisar (String local) async{

    http.Response response = await http.get(

      URL_BASE + "?place_id=$local" +"&fields=name,address_component&key=" +KEY_PLACE

    );

    if( response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok ){


      Map<String, dynamic> dadosJson = json.decode( response.body );
      print( "Data : " + dadosJson["result"]["address_components"][1]["short_name"].toString() );
      print( "Data : " + dadosJson["result"]["address_components"][2]["short_name"].toString() );

    } else {

    }


  }

}
```

Comment: how about looping the result and check if `dadosJson["result"]["address_components"][i]["types"][0]` is administrative_area_1 / administrative_area_2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
List components = dadosJson["result"]["address_components"];

final item1 = components.firstWhere(
    (item) => item["types"].contains("administrative_area_level_1"));

final item2 = components.firstWhere(
    (item) => item["types"].contains("administrative_area_level_1"));

print(item1["short_name"]);
print(item2["short_name"]);
```

Or

```
List components = dadosJson["result"]["address_components"];

final items = components
    .where((item) =>
        item["types"].contains("administrative_area_level_1") ||
        item["types"].contains("administrative_area_level_2"))
    .toList();

items.forEach((item) => print(item["short_name"]));
```

I recommend you to parse the json into an object model, so you don't have to face some type inference problems.

Comment: Hello, it is not working. Error: type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => bool' of 'test'. Is it any problem with the variable DYNAMIC on the map. @PabloBarrera

Comment: still with the same error: '(Map<String, List<dynamic>>) => bool' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => bool' of 'test'. @PabloBarrera